# Поиск боттлнека. Nginx+FastCGI

Tags: nginx, opencart, fastcgi

Есть магазин на Opencart. Страничка товара имеет большой аррей опций, в итоге имеем 1000 одновременных GET-запросов при загрузке страницы с thumbnail-картинками - сами картинки подаются через CDN. Загрузка странички затягивается - поиск подсказывает, что нужен тюнинг Nginx, но применение различных конфигов особо не помогло. Нужен совет, куда копать.

p.s. В конфиге может быть много лишнего, или наоборот - прошу без особых негодований, он пережил море трансформаций :)

p.p.s. Сервер VPS, 2 Гб памяти

```html
user  apache;
worker_processes 2;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 4000;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    
    fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache/ levels=1 keys_zone=fastcgi_cache:64m max_size=256m inactive=1d;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;
    tcp_nodelay     on;

    keepalive_timeout 10;
    send_timeout 120;
    keepalive_requests 10000;
    
    client_body_timeout   15;
    client_header_timeout 15;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
 include /etc/nginx/vhosts/*/*.conf;
 
 
server {
        server_name localhost;
 disable_symlinks if_not_owner;
 include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
 
    
 location @fallback {
  error_log /dev/null crit;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  access_log off ;
 }
 
 location / {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/www-root.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f mysite@mysite.ru";
            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_buffering on;
            fastcgi_buffers 8 512k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 1024k;
            fastcgi_cache_methods GET;
            fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
            fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
            fastcgi_cache_key $request_uri;
            fastcgi_cache fastcgi_cache;
            fastcgi_temp_path /etc/nginx/temp;
            fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
            fastcgi_cache_valid 10s;
            #fastcgi_cache_valid any 10s;
            
            }
    
 listen 80;
    }

}
```

Comment: Хм, у вас картинки через php отдаются?

Comment: Может несколько узких мест - 1. генерация тумб на лету, тогда нужно серверное кеширование 2. не устраивает, что при F5 страница долго перегружается - клиентское кеширование 3. не то, не другое, хотите быстрее грузить - большее сжатие картинок и/или HTTP2. Выбирайте. PS. Не хотите чтобы за картинками nginx лазил к индейцу, используйте это `location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|bmp|txt)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires 14d;
        break;
    }`